# Ruby get page content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby app and I want to detect if a certain piece of Javascript is installed on a website. On most websites it's no problem to fetch the content of this page with the following code:

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.854.0 Safari/535.2"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, 'User-Agent'=>user_agent, 'read_timeout' => '10'), nil, "UTF-8")
```

But on some websites I get a Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired error after 60 seconds. How is it possible that some fetch and some don't and how can I fetch those websites as well?

Comment: may be due to Https connection. Does the websites have SSL on ?

Comment: @Abhinay no it hasn't, and the strange thing is this code works from my local machine, but not from my Digital Ocean droplet

Comment: Do you have IPV6 enabled in DO?

Comment: @Blackcoat77 No we don't have IPv6 enabled.

Comment: @PieterB Could you send for example one URL with which doesn't work from your droplet, and I'll investigate and send you the possible answer?

Comment: @Blackcoat77 That would be great, one of the URL's is www.zetom.nl.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the URL which you provided as much as I could of. Apparently I used the code you posted, from my app which is hosted on Heroku, and it works well. I didn’t have timeout problem. It worked also from my dev local machine as well, like on yours too.

First I thought that problem may be in IPV6 only websites, but no. The client only has A record (IPV4) in DNS zones, and using shared hosting. I also tried to send numerous requests from my Heroku app, just to check if my IP will be banned. It didn’t happen. It may happen that hosting2go (zetom.nl hosting company) blocks DO IP ranges, including your droplet.

It is hard to guess from this point of view what will be the problem. 
You can SSH to your droplet and try:

```
nc -zv 83.137.194.38 80
```

It should return

*`Connection to 83.137.194.38 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!`*

If you get something like:

*`nc: connect to 83.137.194.38 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out`*

Probably there is a problem with your Firewall.

I assume that problem is in DO droplet server configuration. I would first check Firewall of your Droplet, if it’s already set up by filtering incoming and outgoing network traffic based on a set of user-defined rules. If it’s not, I would check with DO support team, as they may implemented some advanced traffic filtering.

If you have Firewall enabled, and you don’t feel comfortable playing with it, you can temporarily disable it just for test purposes, something like (I’m assuming you are on Ubuntu and you have UFW enabled):

```
sudo ufw status verbose # Check if ufw is active
```

In case that is active you can disable it:

```
sudo ufw disable # Will disable ufw firewall
```

This command will reset cloud server rules to default, in case you need it

```
sudo ufw reset
```

I hope it helps a bit as a starting point :-)

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer @Blackcoat77. I have tried this and yes the connection gives a Timeout. I have checked if the firewall was up, but it wasn't (need to fix that). It has to do something with the config of the droplet. Will try to figure out what!